# PowerPoint edit points: eliminate Bezier handles

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Any time I try to edit points of a shape in PowerPoint, the points have Bezier handles, and I want them as corner points.  Selecting the context menu item for straight point or corner point doesn't seem to help.  Basically, I'm looking for an Illustrator equivalent of `shift` + `C` on the point to convert it from curve to corner point.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *right-click* Edit Points then select individual point and ***again*** *right-click* and choose either straight point or corner point.

Typical of MS Office workflows with drawing tools in that it takes multiple clicks through multiple levels of context menus to achieve this  should be simple goal.

***First***, *right-click* and choose **Edit Points**

[image: First Step]

***Choose*** a given single control point (see the bezier handles to see which point is selected)

[image: figure overall]

***Then*** *Right-Click* on that control point to pull up the point-specific context menu and choose **Straight Point** or **Corner Point** to get rid of the bezier curve (keeps the handles but zeros out the curve value)

[image: Final right click]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding Gerard.I have done that.  What I want to do is just get rid of the Bezier handles altogether.  Can that be done?

Comment: My impression from when I had a client who required extensive use of PowerPoint was that *this is in fact how the draw-a-polygon-shape tool actually **works*** - the non-dragged mouse clicks all generate beziers with control handles all of which are zeroed out. I **think** that in fact *all* the PowerPoint drawing shapes work this way - even the *pre-canned* ones like the star - I think if you follow this workflow, you'll find you can edit the control points of *any* of those pre-canned shapes, and *all* of them have beziers which are initially zeroed out to achieve their straight segments.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this too, and I'm starting to wonder if this is a bug. I found a solution to my specific version of this problem. I only got the curved bezier when adding a point in this scenario: I added one point where it adds the bezier points but it shows up as a straight line. I connected a line to that point. When adding a second point to the shape, it throws my rectangle into a curved line. Other than manually moving the point back into position, I couldn't get rid of the curve. But when I disconnect my line from the first point on the shape, I could then add as many points to the shape as I want with no curves to my shape. Then connect the lines and all is well. This makes no sense to me as to why it would be designed this way, but it fixed my issue.

Comment: Hello MNash, according to the other answer it's perfectly possible and not a bug. Thanks for trying to help though, your experience is valuable. Could you [edit] your question to improve the lay-out though and make it a bit more readable? Thanks!